# How to trigger python code upon an event?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I started gathering data to train classification algorithms, but I'd like it to update automatically upon an event.

For example:

```
PerfsL1 = pd.read_html('https://fbref.com/fr/comps/13/stats/Statistiques-Ligue-1#all_stats_standard', header=1)[0]
PerfsL1.to_csv("PerfsL1.csv")
```

However I'd like to it to run automatically whenever there is a game.
To do so I gathered the Calendar:

```
#INPUT 
CalL1 = pd.read_html('https://fbref.com/fr/comps/13/calendrier/Scores-et-tableaux-Ligue-1')
    CalL1 = CalL1[0]
    CalL1.drop(['Attendance', 'Referee', 'Rapport de match', 'Notes'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    ClL1.to_csv('Calendrier_Hisotrique_L1_Saison_2022/2023')

#OUTPUT
  Wk  Day        Date   Time       Domicile   xG Score  xG.1  \
0     1.0  Ven  2022-08-05  21:00           Lyon  1.5   2–1   1.2   
1     1.0  Sam  2022-08-06  17:00     Strasbourg  1.2   1–2   3.2   
2     1.0  Sam  2022-08-06  21:00  Clermont Foot  0.3   0–5   2.6   
3     1.0  Dim  2022-08-07  13:00       Toulouse  1.2   1–1   1.0   
4     1.0  Dim  2022-08-07  15:00          Lille  1.8   4–1   0.9   
..    ...  ...         ...    ...            ...  ...   ...   ...   
414  38.0  Sam  2023-06-03    NaN        Ajaccio  NaN   NaN   NaN   
415  38.0  Sam  2023-06-03    NaN         Monaco  NaN   NaN   NaN   
416  38.0  Sam  2023-06-03    NaN      Paris S-G  NaN   NaN   NaN   
417  38.0  Sam  2023-06-03    NaN           Nice  NaN   NaN   NaN   
418  38.0  Sam  2023-06-03    NaN          Brest  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

**So, is there a way for the first code to run anytime the date matches a game's date ?**

Thank you for your support and have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options to do it, here is one of them:

Using [crontab](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/) module. You can basically create events that will be run at a certain time in a certain day. You only have to create dynamically these events using the dates in your csv. For each date you'll create an event and they will run at that time. The only thing is that this requires you to run the script as a server and to put it as `automatically starting service` on your machine (in case of a restart, the script will automatically run again an create the events again). For setting your server as a windows service so you can set auto-start for it you can use [nssm](https://nssm.cc/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
However, I've been trying to schedule my python but I am totally lost, even with all these tutorials... Any chance we could chat for a minute ?